# How to calculate the revolutions of BLDC motor?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, interrupts

A brushless DC motor is rotating at 5000 rpm and is fitted with 3 hall effect sensors. The
microcontroller interfaced with the brushless motor has a clock speed of 2 KHz and is
configured to trigger an interrupt service routine every time there is a rising or falling edge
detected from the 3 hall effect sensors via GPIO pins (for 1 revolution of the motor this will
trigger 6 interrupts in total). The interrupts via the GPIO lines on each hall effect sensor
have been mapped to one interrupt service routine for code efficiency. The interrupt service
routine for the hall effect sensors takes exactly 40 clock cycles to execute.

**How many revolutions will the brushless DC motor rotate after one interrupt has been fully
executed?**

Comment: Is this homework? Because it sounds like homework.

Comment: It's a simple mathematical problem. What part are you having trouble with?